# Analyze the Clauses

Tags: clauses

My question is how to analyze the clauses in the following sentence:

> The only thing Harry liked about his appearance was a very thin scar on his forehead that was shaped like a bolt of lightning.

Answer (score 1):

In the sentence:

> The only thing Harry liked about his appearance was a very thin scar on his forehead that was shaped like a bolt of lightning.

there are two defining relative clauses:

- (that) Harry liked
- that was shaped like a bolt of lightning

*(that) Harry liked* has *the only thing (about his appearance)* as antecedent.

*that was shaped like a bolt of lightning* has *a very thin scar on his forehead* as antecedent.

Comment: A small point: in integrated relatives, the antecedents are nominals, not NPs, so determiners are omitted.

Answer (score 1):

It's a pair of noun phrases, each with a relative clause and some modifiers.

> [Something] was [something else]

The basic sentence:

> The **thing** was a **scar**

Adding the relative clauses that modify the nouns:

> The thing **(that) Harry liked**  was a scar **that was shaped like a lightning bolt**

And then some modifiers:

> The **only** thing Harry liked **about his appearance** was a **very thin** scar that was shaped like a lightning bolt.